# Dependant dll not copied to application build folder

Tags: c#, .net

I've been facing this issue recurrently for sometime and I'd like now to understand if what I've facing is to be expected or what. I have a windows forms application that references a custom .NET standard library (source code in the same solution) that references newtonsoft.json.dll and when compiling the winform app, newtonsoft.json.dll does not get copied to the application output folder. I usually address this issue by adding a reference to newtonsoft.json.dll on the application but is this the correct approach? Even creating a brand new winform application and adding a reference to my custom library, the required newtonsoft.json.dll does not lend in the build output folder. Before anyone suggests it, the copy local setting is set to true on the windows form application for my custom .NET standard library. What I don't get is if this issue is to be expected or not.

Comment: why don't you install the newtonsoft nuget package in your main solution as well

Answer (score 0):

install same version of newton soft json in both projects through nuget package

Comment: Yes @Atok and Santosh Tarlapally I could.....apart the fact that the windows forms app is targeting .NET framework while the library that references newtonsoft.json.dll is targeting .NET standard but the question remains, is this situation to be expected and why? Instead of adding a reference I added a post build action that copies newtonsoft.json.dll to the app build folder.

Comment: btw, just stumbled on another .NET standard library that references the nuget library System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager and once more this does not get copied to the application build folder. Adding all these libraries as references also on the application project just to have them copied to the app build folder looks to me so ridiculous.